# Discord Bot "Status" from Playing to Watching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm hoping to change my discord's bot status from "Playing" to "Watching" or any of the other options but can not understand where to declare this at, can someone please help me? This is the line of code I have for the current status:

```
client.user.setActivity(`${client.users.size} in here buying the dip on AAPL`);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [setActivity](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity), you just aren't using it correctly if you want to change it to watching.

```
client.user.setActivity('YouTube', { type: 'WATCHING' });
```

This is how you should do it, `WATCHING` can also be replaced by `LISTENING`, `PLAYING` and `STREAMING`, these are all of part of [Activity Type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ClientUser#setPresence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence):

```
client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with discord.js' , type: 'WATCHING' }, status: 'idle' })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will change your status every 10 seconds.You can set time at the end of the code

```
 const activities_list = [ 
    "Playing", 
    "Watching"
    ]; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
    }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
});
```

Comment: The rate-limit for this is 5/60s so updating every 10 seconds will lose at least 1 update every minute. The recommended interval is at least 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, the first time I tried using it, it's awfully simple and when the bot is online it'll say '{Your bot's name} is now online!'.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is now watching online!`)
    bot.user.setActivity('Youtube', ({type: "WATCHING"}))
})
```

Hope this works, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

If your bot doesn't update the status using the other answers' code, try this:

```js
client.user.setActivity('the best show', { type: ActivityType.Watching });
```

(My bot didn't want to play nicely with the `{ type: 'WATCHING' }`)

Your bot also needs Presence Intent toggled to on in the Discord Developer Portal

Answer (score 0):

```
client.user.setActivity(`${client.users.size} in here buying the dip on AAPL`,{type: 'Watching'});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.